# Obj/C: Sorting an array on a custom order

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

I've got an array of NSMutableDictionaries, containing (amongst others) the key Location. 
I need to sort the array to input it into a table. On top should be N, below should be A, and below that should be R.
So in sort: How can I sort an array in the order: N - A - R?

EDIT: I can order by looking at two variables, but I'm using more then 2 variables (7 in total)...

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your array is mutable, you can sort it using the -sortUsing... methods. If not, you can create a new, sorted array using the -sortedArrayUsing... methods. For example, there are -sortUsingComparator: and -sortedArrayUsingComparator: methods which take a comparator block as a parameter. You just need to supply a block that compares two objects using your custom sort order, like this:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    NSString *firstKey = [firstObject valueForKey:@"location"];
    NSString *secondKey = [secondObject valueForKey:@"location"];
    if ([firstKey stringEqual:@"N"] || [lastKey stringEqual:@"R"])
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if ([firstKey stringEqual:secondKey])
        return NSOrderedSame;
    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

There's a pretty thorough discussion of sorting arrays, with examples, in the [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) document.

Comment: @Caleb thanks Caleb, that helped me out a bit. I'm still struggling with sorting more Locations, N appears on top but all the letters below appear together, but on random sort. My total location list should be N-G-B-A-F-C. So for example, all the A are together, but not directly below B. The order sorted is N-B-C-F-A-G. I'm using the block you used multiple times, perhaps something is going wrong there...?

Comment: @Caleb ofcourse, using this block multiple times won't work (and wanders off randomly). Posted the previous comment a bit too fast without enough thinking. Though, using two keys works for me, but using more then 2 (which I need) is where i struggle. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Joetjah, I'm not sure what you mean about using the block multiple times. I wouldn't necessarily recommend using exactly that code, either, especially if you have more than just the three values you indicated originally. I was really just giving something quick and dirty as an example. A better way to go for more values might be to define the order as a string: @"NBCFAG". Then you could find the location value of each dictionary in the string and compare their indices. This scales much better to larger numbers of possible values.

Comment: @Caleb So, how would I be able to sort the array with all its dictionaries, using that string? Sorry for bothering you too much, haha...

Comment: @Joetjah, you'd get the value for each dictionary as I've done in the code I posted. Then find each value in the order string. You could use -rangeOfString: for this. Finally, compare the indices (the beginning of each range) to figure out which value occurs first in the order string, and should thus be ordered first. You don't have to use a NSString to define the order... you could use an array, a C string, or any other way that makes it easy for you to define an ordered set of characters.

Comment: @Caleb that should do it then... I'll try something in a few minutes ^^ Thanks for the help!